# What is causing these strange characters?

Tags: bash, terminal

I've been using a CentOS 7.1 VPS for quite some time now, and although I hadn't touched it in a while, I was doing some maintenance and noticed when I went to remove a file, I got the following message:

[image]

I know that strange characters can occur because of a difference in terminal or character base, but I have the following settings in `env`:
(Removing unnecessary pieces)

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
TERM=xterm
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

(Note I have omitted `LS_COLORS` because it is insanely long, but I recognize that could also possibly be the cause.)

I've not had to deal with these kinds of characters before, so I'm kind of at a loss where to look, and I don't really want to start randomly changing settings for fear of making something worse, but basically just looking for causes of these characters. Thanks for reading.

Comment: How are you accessing the VPS? it looks to me like the encoding on your (SSH?) client is set up incorrectly

Comment: I'm accessing via putty, but I haven't changed the putty config for ages, and this hasn't happened before. I'll check the settings nonetheless...

Comment: Interesting -- the character set, which has never been changed (and default set to ISO-8859-1:1998 (Latin-1, West Europe), was the culprit. I changed it to UTF and it went away. Apparently West Europe doesn't use the same type of writer-style single quotes that UTF does.  (Make that an answer and I'll be glad to accept it.. so simple)

Comment: Should not be off-topic, because it is reproducible, and represents an issue that users of UNIX-Linux systems may face.  Knowledge of character sets and their implications and impact on our systems is important to preserve.

Comment: @xalorous "closed" here just means that the only answer is to correct the "mistake". The question and answer aren't deleted; the closing is just a signal to focus your Answering time on other Q's.

Comment: Honestly I don't see this as a "typo" being fixed. This is a default setting in putty that can cause easily reproducible effects, whereas many users may not be able to fix it. I'd hardly call it a typo. Regardless, if it's kept here for posterity, that's good enough for me, even if I think the off-topic categorization is wrong.

Comment: @JeffSchaller if the OP marks the question answered it achieves your stated purpose.  If the question is closed for being off topic, it is removed and no longer visible, or I completely misunderstand the process.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This looks like an encoding mismatch between your remote environment and the SSH client. In particular, PuTTY (at least on Windows) defaults to ISO-8859-1:1998 (Latin-1, West Europe) whereas you are using UTF-8 on the server side.

The PuTTY setting to correct this is under the Window -> Translation menu; go to the 'Remote character set' dropdown and select 'UTF-8'.